# How to connect from ruby to MS Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, ruby, sql-server-2005, odbc

I'm trying to connect to the sql server 2005 database from *NIX machine:

I have the following configuration: Linux 64bit

> ruby -v
>   ruby 1.8.6 (2007-09-24 patchlevel 111) [x86_64-linux]
>   important gems:
>   dbd-odbc (0.2.4)
>   dbi (0.4.1)
>   active record sql server adapter - as plugin

ruby-odbc 0.9996 (installed without any options.)
unixODBC is installed
freeTDS is installed

> cat /etc/odbcinst.ini

```
  [FreeTDS]
     Description     = TDS driver (Sybase/MS SQL)
     Driver          = /usr/lib/libtdsodbc.so
     Setup           = /usr/lib/odbc/libtdsS.so
     CPTimeout       =
     CPReuse         =
     FileUsage       = 1
```

DSN:

```
DRIVER=FreeTDS;TDS_Version=8.0;SERVER=XXXX;DATABASE=XXX;Port=1433;uid=XXX;pwd=XXXX;"
```

or

```
DRIVER=/usr/lib/libtdsodbc.so;TDS_Version=8.0;SERVER=XXXX;DATABASE=XXX;Port=1433;uid=XXX;pwd=XXXX;"
```

I receive the following error:

```
>>ActiveRecord::Base.sqlserver_connection({"mode"=>"ODBC", "adapter"=>"sqlserver", "dsn"=>my_dns)
DBI::DatabaseError: IM002 (0) [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/DBD/ODBC/ODBC.rb:95:in `connect'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/dbi.rb:424:in `connect'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/dbi.rb:215:in `connect'
    from /opt/ublip/rails/current/vendor/plugins/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter.rb:47:in `sqlserver_connection'
```

It looks like ODBC unable to find appropriate ODBC driver, but I have no ideas why.

I had a problem with /usr/lib/libtdsodbc.so which is empty in default debian package free-tds dev, but i solved it with remove broken package and installation from sources.

Will appreciate any thought!

Note:
I'm albe to connect using the same steps on mac 10.5

Comment: First things first: what version of Ruby are you using on "mac 10.5" ? I think 1.8.6 may be the issue. Also .. What version of Activerecord are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This looks close, and I've gotten the same type of setup to work on Ubuntu 8.04 (with Ruby 1.8.6.) Since this is on Debian, it should be the similar.

These packages should be installed: unixodbc unixodbc-dev freetds-dev libdbd-odbc-ruby tdsodbc

/etc/odbcinst.ini should have something like this:

```
[FreeTDS]
Description = FreeTDS unixODBC Driver
Driver = /usr/lib/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup = /usr/lib/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
UsageCount = 1
```

And /etc/freetds/freetds.conf: (where XXX is the database name and NNN... is the IP of the server):

```
[XXX]
  host = NNN.NNN.NNN.NNN
  tds version = 8.0
  client charset = UTF-8
  text size = 262144
  port = 1433
```

Then to connect:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.sqlserver_connection({"mode"=>"ODBC", 
  "adapter"=>"sqlserver", 
  "dsn"=>"DRIVER=FreeTDS;SERVERNAME=XXX;DATABASE=XXX;uid=XXX;pwd=XXX"
)
```

Comment: A much better walkthrough is here: http://wiki.github.com/rails-sqlserver/2000-2005-adapter/platform-installation-ubuntu-2

Comment: Hi, I am trying to use your example but I get this error **S1000 (0) [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source **